# How to return an array of ParseObject from CloudCode call

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

There is a parse CloudCode function created as such:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("getCurrentEvents", function(request, response) {
    var TimedEvent = Parse.Object.extend("TimedEvent");
    var query = new Parse.Query(TimedEvent);
    query.greaterThan("expiresOn", new Date());
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            response.success(results);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error("There was an error while looking for TimedEvents");
        }
    });
});
```

It returns an array of TimedEvent, as shown in the curl test here:

```
{"result":[{"expiresOn":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-07-31T22:31:00.000Z"},"playMode":"Normal","tableId":"Carnival","objectId":"J1LSO3EnKi","createdAt":"2014-07-28T21:48:22.983Z","updatedAt":"2014-07-28T22:32:14.304Z","__type":"Object","className":"TimedEvent"}]}
```

When trying to access it from Unity SDK however, I get a "cannot convert to destination type" exception with the following line:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Parse.ParseObject[]> task = 
               Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<Parse.ParseObject[]> ("getCurrentEvents", parameters);
```

I also tried

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IEnumerable<Parse.ParseObject>> task = 
               Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IEnumerable<Parse.ParseObject[]>> ("getCurrentEvents", parameters);
```

with the same (lack of) results. What kind of signature is the SDK expecting?

Comment: I have the same problem? Did you come up with an solution to this?

Comment: Nope. Parse.com doesn't seem to monitor this, contrary to what the support website says.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (without IEnumerable?):

```
Threading.Tasks.Task<Parse.ParseObject> task = Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<Parse.ParseObject>("getCurrentEvents", parameters);
```

But better yet, you could extend ParseObject to create your own TimedEvent class in Unity, like this:

```
[ParseClassName("TimeEvent")]
public class TimeEvent : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName("expiresOn")]
    public DateTime expiresOn
    {
        get { return GetProperty<DateTime>("expiresOn"); }
        set { SetProperty(value, "expiresOn"); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("playMode")]
    public string playMode
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>("playMode"); }
        set { SetProperty(value, "playMode"); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName("tableId")]
    public string tableId
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>("tableId"); }
        set { SetProperty(value, "tableId"); }
    }

    // any other fields you want to access
}
```

Then you can query your data like this:

```
IEnumerator getTimedEvents(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    var cloudTask = Parse.ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<TimeEvent>("getCurrentEvents", parameters);
    while (!cloudTask.IsCompleted)
        yield return null;

    if (cloudTask.IsCanceled || cloudTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        // handle error
    }
    else
    {
        TimeEvent t = cloudTask.Result;
        // do stuff with t
    }
}
```

P.S. Don't forget to register your Parse class somewhere (I usually do it in the Awake() of an early GameObject). In your case, you would do it like this:

```
Parse.ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<TimedEvent>();
```